# Override classloading for a specifc java class file in a wildfly/jboss module

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, classloading

I want to overwrite a particular java class present in a JBoss/Wildfly module with my own customizations. If I use tomcat server, all I need to do, place the customized class files in WEB-INF/classes. Since classes present in WEB-INF/classes takes precedence over the class files present in a particular jar file under WEB-INF/lib. Is there any similar way available for Wildfly server?

Comment: What type of class are you trying to override? In most cases classes in the `WEB-INF/classes` will be loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is you can write your own class-loading logic.

```
URLClassLoader loader;
//create object and initialize URLClassLoader loader with the corrosponding classes or jar from //specific location

//Get the 'className' by iterating Jar or by listing class files

Class c = cl.loadClass(className);
```